# How to sort column ASC using vue-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-data-tables

I am using https://github.com/AndreSouzaAbreu/vue-data-table.

actually i want to sort marks column in ASC.

```
columns: [
          {
            key: "12",
            index: 0,
            title: "Mark",
          },
          {
            key: "09",
            title: "Name",
            sortable: true,
            index: 1,
          }
    ]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include a text-based [mcve]

Comment: Try this : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-sorting